# Angular newbie question regarding packages install

Tags: npm, package, cdn

I make this question because of a problem I'm having making "bootstrap-select" to work with Bootstrap 4, but its a rather general conceptual question. Let's go:

What's the difference between installing a package and just referencing its css/js in html? Let's take bootstrap-select as an example:

I can put the references I paste below inside index.html and bootstrap-select will work (or at least it should) but I can also install package with "npm install bootstrap-select" so what's really the difference between both approaches? It is one of them just enough for make the package to work? Are both steps required? What's a best practice?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.js" />
```

Another example, documentation says bootstrap-select requires Popper so it's enough to add this next script reference to index.html or instead I should install popper through npm install popper? Or I should do both?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" />
```

Comment: Both ways are fine. However NPM is used for managing pakets and their versions and dependencies. If it's just one dependency you need your approach is ok. The thing is, Angular uses NPM to use the packages in their code. You have things like webpack and so on, which give you a development enviroment

Comment: If you don't have internet or they remove that file from cdn, then it wouldn't work. It's always better to have a local copy IMO.

Comment: Try to read about NPM, what it is, how it works and how it relates to NodeJS

Comment: Thanks for all the kind responses guys, of course I'll read but wanted to have a quick idea on the subject. One more question, if I install a package through npm and iit is stored internally into node_modules that means the css/js reference in html is no longer necessary? In case it still is, how do I reference those files inside node_module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, the best practice is to install and get into node_module. my reason for that would be

1. You need to be connected to the internet while loading the application (Package won't load when you're running in intraNet.
2. You might never know when would the package CND is updated and you might face some issues after updates.

Feel free to correct me :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind response @Abhishek Ekaanth. That means that if you just install with npm then you don't need the css/js reference in html? Or in case you still do how to reference files in node_modules?

Comment: When you do an install you don't need CND.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended by angular that you use angular.cli.json(angular version 4) and angualr.json in (angular 5) Rather than declaring the js files in index.html, this keeps your code clean. And installing through npm is easy and reduces the effort for the js version updates as well.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply @Kallam. I'll mark Abhishek Ekaanth just because answer is similar and he replied firts but your answer was very helpful to me.